# How to get minimum value of an element combination of str and int in a list

Tags: python, list

Creating list of name and price, this will be the given list:

```
alist = [["Chanel-1000, Dior-2000, Prada"],["Chloe-200,Givenchy-400,LV-600"],["Bag-1,Bagg-2,Baggg-3"]]
```

To get minimum value of each element
This will be the output:

```
chanel-1000,chloe-200,bag-1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Check out this code:**
1 .If u want output based on integer tag of each name then use the method.

```
alist = [["Chanel-1000, Dior-2000, Prada-500"],
         ["Chloe-200,Givenchy-400,LV-600"], ["Bag-1,Bagg-2,Baggg-3"]]

alist_min = [
    min(map(str.strip, x[0].split(',')),
        key=lambda i: int(str.strip(i).split('-')[-1])) for x in alist
]
print(alist_min)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
['Prada-500', 'Chloe-200', 'Bag-1']
```

---

2 .If u want output based on name tag of each name then use the method.

```
alist = [
    ["Chanel-1000, Dior-2000, Prada"],
    ["Chloe-200,Givenchy-400,LV-600"],
    ["Bag-1,Bagg-2,Baggg-3"]]

alist_min = [min(map(str.strip, x[0].split(','))) for x in alist]
print(alist_min)
```

Now u can use this `alist_min` object to get required output.

Comment: There's an output but I try to shuffle or change the price of an item it cant get the minimum value like ["Chanel-1000, Dior-500, Prada-600"] it will still give the result of 
#Chanel-1000, etc etc. instead of Dior-500 which has the least value within an element

Comment: @ppd2021 be sure to follow the stackoverflow guidelines before asking any questions, u should provide enough explanation of problem

Comment: same result as the first code here's another example
alist = [
    ["Chanel-1000, Dior-2000, Prada-95"],
    ["Chloe-400,Givenchy-200,LV-600"],
    ["Bag-1,Bagg-2,Baggg-3"]]

It should be like this 
Prada-95, givenchy-200, bagg-1 <- trying to get the minimum value

Comment: @ppd2021 use first method and o/p I got is `['Prada-95', 'Givenchy-200', 'Bag-1']`

Comment: @ppd2021 hope u got your solution :) as u accepted it

Comment: yea! @exploorex got this thanks! , is that possible using define function?

Answer (score 2):

Use `min()` along with a list comprehension:

```py
alist = [["Chanel-1000, Dior-2000, Prada"],["Chloe-200,Givenchy-400,LV-600"],["Bag-1,Bagg-2,Baggg-3"]]
alist_min = [min(re.split(r',\s*', x[0])) for x in alist]
print(alist_min)  # ['Chanel-1000', 'Chloe-200', 'Bag-1']
```

Comment: re is not defined

Comment: Add `import re` to the top of your Python script.  Typically, we omit import statements in our answers as they can clutter the answer itself.